# Htaccess RewriteRule if none of the following

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

## The situation:

1. An old Wordpress website has been replaced by a new Wordpress
   multisite (ROOT, nl, en) and the links have changed.
2. I want to redirect the traffic coming in from the old URLs to the new URLs (eg. /cases --> /nl/blog)

---

## The rule set:

```
URI is empty         --> redirect to /nl (default language)
URI is /en OR /nl    --> redirect to /en/ OR /nl/ (add forward slash)

URI is /oldurl1      --> redirect to /newurl1
URI is /oldurl2      --> redirect to /newurl2
...
URI is /oldurlX      --> redirect to /newurlX

URI is NOT ANY of the known old URLs or new ones --> show nl/404
```

Without the last line, the default Wordpress 404 doesn't show up, but instead the browser 404 comes up.

---

## Trial and failiure:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /


# URI is empty --> redirect to /nl (default language)
RewriteRule ^$ nl/ [R=301,L]
    
# URI is /en OR /nl --> redirect to /en/ OR /nl/ (add forward slash)
RewriteRule ^(en|nl)$  $1/ [R=301,L]
    
# URI is /oldurl1 --> redirect to /newurl1
RewriteRule ^(oldurl1|oldurl1/)$  nl/newurl1/ [R=301,L]
    
# URI is NOT ANY of the known old URLs or new ones --> show nl/404
RewriteRule !^(nl|en|nl/|en/|oldurl1|oldurlX......this can't be right)$  nl/404
```

---

## The question

What would be an efficient way of directing all unknown URLs to the 404 page?

Answer (score 0):

Well every WordPress theme can use its own 404 error page. There are also plugins that allow customizing the default Wordpress 404 page